# Unable to get tab order working within NSPopover

Tags: macos, cocoa, nspopover

I have a View within an NSPopover, and I am unable to set the tab order correctly. I have set the nextKeyView within my 4 text fields. But it tends to flip from TextField1 to Search1, instead of TextField1 -> TextField2. I have tried inserting [self.view.window makeFirstResponder:textField1] also [self.view.window setInitialFirstResponder:textField1] along with recalculatekeyviewloop but with no luck.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem when composing the popover-view of certain subviews programatically in awakeFromNIB. I could solve the problem by inserting the subviews after the popover had its private NSPopoverWindow set (i.e. it was shown the first time). It seems like the popover is re-evaluating the view-loop when the popover-view is embedded in the private child-window - ignoring the view-loop given in the view.

You could try the following:

```
-(void) popoverDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification{  // NSPopoverDelegate-method
    if (!popoverDidShowForTheFirstTime){
        [self setUpViews];
    }...


-(void) setUpViews{
   popoverDidShowForTheFirstTime = YES;
   // insert views and establish nextKeyViews ...
```